# Web Application Template Generator

Tags: java, spring, jpa, web

Are there any Web Application Template Generators...

Something that would generate a Template Web application for me using the following technologies (or whatever i choose):
Spring MVC
Spring Security
JPA
Hibernate
JQuery

Idea is to have all the mundane stuff, already in place.
I found 'appfuse', but i can't find meaningful documentation on it.
Its QuickStart application uses Struts(instead of Spring mvc) - which i do not want to use.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Your question is a little bit too broad, and it's asking to find a tool, so it's not really for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Spring Roo is what you are looking for.

Spring Roo can easily generate configuration and sample template for most technologies which you mentioned.